# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in console

Tags: javascript

My Function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeImage(img)
 {
    document.getElementById("saleDetailDivGetImg").src=img;
    alert(img);
}
</script>
```

My Function Onclick

```
items+='<img src='+item.product_image1+' id="saleDetailDivGetImg">';
items+="<img src="+item.product_image2+"  onclick='changeImage("+item.product_image2+");'>";
```

Comment: You are generating invalid JS. Look at the **generated** HTML. Either way, what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Since `item.product_image2` is a URL string, you need to put it in quotes when you call `changeImage`.

```
items+="<img src="+item.product_image2+"  onclick='changeImage(\""+item.product_image2+"\");'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add Quotes with the text like

```
items+="<img src="+item.product_image2+"  onclick='changeImage(&quot;"+item.product_image2+"&quot;)'>";
```

And then you are able to pass string with space also to the function.